# Python Script in LibreOffice Calc doesn't refresh automatically it's variables

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to know the number of the last row in my Table to work on it. So, I wrote this function in Python:

```
def find_last_cell(cursor):
    cursor.gotoEnd()
    last_cell = sheetCalc.getCellRangeByName(cursorCalc.AbsoluteName)
    last_column = last_cell.CellAddress.Column
    last_row = last_cell.CellAddress.Row

    return last_column, last_row
```

And I wrote this in my "main" function:

```
def calcula(oEvent):

    column_1, row_1 = find_last_cell(cursorCalc)
    write_Value(column_1, sheetCalc, 2, 28) #Just for debug
    write_Value(row_1, sheetCalc, 2, 29) #Just for debug

    #fill_qtd(row_1)
    #fill_tension(row_1)
    #fill_fp(row_1)


    return 0
```

**Problem:**

It works well in the first use:
[image: First use]

But, when I modify the Table an press the button, it maintains the same results:
[image: Second use]

**Debugs:**

- If I go to File >> Refresh, this error comes out when I press the button again:

> com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException:  (Error during invoking function calcula in module file:///C:/Users/34471945882/AppData/Roaming/LibreOffice/4/user/Scripts/python/Calc_Inst.py (<class 'uno.com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException'>:
> File "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\pythonscript.py", line 915, in invoke
> ret = self.func( *args )
> File "C:\Users\34471945882\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python\Calc_Inst.py", line 154, in calcula
> column_1, row_1 = find_last_cell(cursorCalc)        #Verifica a última célula ocupada
> File "C:\Users\34471945882\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python\Calc_Inst.py", line 95, in find_last_cell
> last_cell = sheetCalc.getCellRangeByName(cursorCalc.AbsoluteName)   #Seleciona a última célula
> ))

- If I make any modification in my python file (add a comment, for example) and save again, it works. But I need to do this for each modification in table, what makes it unusual for the user.

**Question:** How can I correct this behavior? I want to use the button for any times without need to refresh or modify the python file?

LibreOffice Version:
Version: 7.2.5.2 (x64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 499f9727c189e6ef3471021d6132d4c694f357e5
CPU threads: 4; OS: Windows 6.3 Build 9600; UI render: Skia/Raster; VCL: win
Locale: pt-BR (pt_BR); UI: pt-BR
Calc: CL

Comment: `cursorCalc.AbsoluteName` - did you mean `cursor.AbsoluteName`? Also, where does `cursorCalc` get defined? If it is a global variable, then that is likely the problem.

Comment: @JimK, yes, it's all defined in the beginning of my python file:
sheets = document.getSheets(); 
sheetCalc = sheets.getByName('Calculadora');
cursorCalc = sheetCalc.createCursor().
It's a global variable. But why is it the problem?

Comment: Right, so if it's global then it will not get the changed value. Initialize those values at the beginning of `calcula()` instead, and get rid of all the global variables. They are not needed. The initial part of the code only gets run once, when the python file gets modified, as you have already discovered. It's a good place to declare constants but not variables.

Comment: Thank you @JimK, it's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global variables in programming are usually a bad idea, and this is no exception. From the comment:

> If it's global then it will not get the changed value. Initialize those values at the beginning of `calcula()` instead... The initial part of the code only gets run once, when the python file gets modified, as you have already discovered. It's a good place to declare constants but not variables.